# Setting a Parsed value as variable in a batch script

Tags: parsing, batch-file, scripting

So I'm having a difficult time with this, I am trying to parse a txt file for a specific value and add it to a variable, but just not getting it to work correctly I am using the following code

```
for /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%a in ('findstr /I "Short part of line 00:00" test.txt') do set "var1=%%a"
```

The problem is that there are other similar lines of text that vary a slight amount, I'm including a phrase that is unique when considered in whole, but I don't think the command is taking that into consideration? the file is always the same in regards to size, is there anyway to re write this to find a token on a specific line and assign to a variable instead?

EDIT:

```
input.txt

Process 1                   

Primary process Started            2:50:00
Primary Last part process          3:40:52
Primary part 3 Balanced            5:01:55
Primary CMD Backup Completed       5:04:13
Primary Process Balance Completed  5:04:13


Process 2       

Secondary process Started            2:50:00
Secondary Last part process          3:42:08
Secondary part 3 Balanced            5:06:38
Secondary CMD Backup Completed       5:08:56
Secondary Process Balance Completed  5:08:56
```

So if I were to use the command:

```
for /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%a in ('findstr /I "Primary process Started" test.txt') do set "var1=%%a"
```

I should read back 2:50:00 instead I'm getting 5:08:56 thats the weird one, the rest are simply flipped so "Primary part 3 Balanced" will give me back the time for "Secondary part 3 Balanced"

Comment: Difficult to help without snippets of your input data. How about posting at least one line you want to match and one line you are erroneously matching right now?

Comment: Please post the exact line you want to parse and the substring you want to extract from it.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm getting your question right: You want to find the line starting with `Primary process Started`, extract the time (in this case 2:50:00) and store it in a variable `var1`?

Comment: You need to use the /C option! You are also using the wrong token.

Comment: That is exactly what I am wanting to do :)

Comment: If you happened to read the help for the FINDSTR command. **Use spaces to separate multiple search strings unless the argument is prefixed with /C.  For example, 'FINDSTR "hello there" x.y' searches for "hello" or "there" in file x.y.  'FINDSTR /C:"hello there" x.y' searches for "hello there" in file x.y.**

Comment: Ok it appears it is picking the word "Process" out of the "String" and moving down every line and then setting the time to any line with the word process as the variable so it ends up to the very last line which includes the word and sets it as var1. I tried /C and removing /I and both make no difference, so the question is why is it searching for the 2nd word in the string?

Comment: Squashman you are the man!!! Thank you so much for that! that fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments this should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (input.txt) do (
    set line=%%f
    if "!line:~0,23!"=="Primary process Started" (
        for /f "tokens=4" %%t in ("%%f") do set var1=%%t
        goto BREAK
    )
)
:BREAK
echo %var1%
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying @MichaelS code a little bit.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims= " %%G in (input.txt) do (
    if "%%G %%H %%I"=="Primary process Started" (
        set var1=%%J
        GOTO BREAK
    )
)
:BREAK
echo %var1%
```